# Getting the element of a cell of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am using a datatable from this site:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

I want to get the data from a specific cell (the first one) of the selected row.
is this possible?

With

```
 table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
```

I can get the selected row and delete it (it is described on the website) but I don't know how to get a value of a cell.

If you have any suggestions I would be very thankful.

Comment: This is javascript, not C#, right? To answer your question, you can grab the first cell right from jQuery with `$('#{table-id} .selected td:first')` or get a list of all of the cells with `$('#{table-id} .selected td')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the selected row, then the data, and we want the first property so we select the first index (which is 0)

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/bsctx3f4/4/))

```
$('#button').click( function () {
    alert(table.row('.selected').data()[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works, is it the same for the second column (td:second-child)?
Do you know whether I can select a row at the beginning, which means, when the user opens this site, maybe the second row should be selected automatically. Is there any option?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for

```
table.row('.selected').data()
```

You can do something like

```
var d = table.row('.selected').data();
```

then reference whatever the column is with

```
alert(d.MyColumnName);  // Returns the value of the selected row & column.
```

This assumes you are using DataTables 1.10 or higher.

Comment: Thank you, is MyColumnName in the example on the linked site "Name", "Position" or what do I have to specify?

Comment: when you initialize your DataTable, in the "columns" group, you can name and give info about the column.  (e.g. https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name )  You can also hide the columns etc. here.  "MyColumnName" would be whatever you named the column here.

Comment: This may also be of use to you: https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector